# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn Scroll Listener

Tags: android, list, android-jetpack-compose

I want to programmatically change which tab is selected as the user scrolls past each "see more" item in the list below.  How would I best accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Ryan M writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67681161/4362643), you can use `LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex`. The magic of Compose is that you can just use it in an `if` statement and Compose will do the work. Look at the following example, which displays a different text based on the first visible item. Similarly, you can select a different tab based on the first visible item.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val listState = rememberLazyListState()

            Column {
                Text(if (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex < 100) "< 100" else ">= 100")
                LazyColumn(state = listState) {
                    items(1000) {
                        Text(
                            text = "$it",
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `val firstVisibleIndex by derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }`
Accessing listState.firstVisibleItemIndex directly inside compose function might have an effect on performance.

Comment: Be careful using this property. According to documentation, this property is observable and if you use it in the composable function it will be recomposed on every change causing potential performance issues.
If you want to run some side effects like sending an analytics event or updating a state based on this value consider using "snapshotFlow"

Answer (score 24):

Just create a `NestedScrollConnection` and assign it to parent view `nestedScroll` modifier:

```
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            // called when you scroll the content
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

Assign it to `LazyColumn` or to its parent composed view:

```
Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
```

Exemple:

```
LazyColumn(
    ...
    modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
) {
    items(...) {
       Text("Your text...")
    }
}
```

Comment: good and simple answer... thanks :)

Comment: If you want to get a consumed value instead of the available one, you should override ```onPostScroll``` function and take Y value from ```val delta = consumed.y```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#firstVisibleItemIndex()) property (obtained via `rememberLazyListState` and set as the `state` parameter to `LazyColumn`) and set the current tab based on that.

Reading that property is considered a model read in Compose, so it will trigger a recomposition whenever the first visible item changes.

If you instead want to do something more complex based on more than just the first visible item, you can use [`LazyListState.layoutInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#layoutInfo()) to get information about *all* visible items and their locations, rather than just the first.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the implementation?  How exactly would I use LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex to changed the current tab?

Comment: The problem with `layoutInfo` is that it triggers recomposition. Probably it is a bug in compose.

Comment: @DmytroIvanov Reading a piece of state will indeed trigger recomposition when that state changes.  That's working as intended.  What are you experiencing that you believe is a bug?

Comment: Actually, I realized that it is not a bug, yeah it is basically a recomposition because we read a state.